# Table to Distance Between in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, distance, table, st-distance

I am a new user in PostGIS.
I need to create a table with the ID_DIR of table A, ID_SQ of table B and have a new column called "Distance" that would be the distance between the ID_DIR and the ID_SQ in a zone of influence of 500 meters of each ID_SQ.
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE RESULT AS (
   SELECT a.ID_DIR,
          ST_AsTEXT(ST_Shortesline(a.geom,b.geom) AS geom,
          a.ID_SQ, 
          ST_Length(
            St_Shortesline(a.geom,b.geom)::geography/1000) AS Distance 
   FROM TABLE_A AS a, 
        TABLE_B AS b 
   WHERE ST_Dwithin (a.geom,b.geom,500) 
   ORDER BY a.ID_DIR,Distance ASC
);
```

I have two problems:
1) This query does not work
2) I have seen that the processing time in these examples is very high. Table A has 4 million data and it is duplicated depending on the times it crosses with the ID_SQ buffer
Help!

Comment: Please expand "query does not work" - are you getting errors (specify details), or unexpected results (again details), query runs forever, etc?

Comment: in addition to @JGH's answer, and since you are new to PostGIS: it's essential to have a spatial index in place on (at least one, but better go for) both geometry columns. if you go with the on-the-fly cast to `GEOGRAPHY` (instead of projecting or a type change), I'd suggest to use a functional index like `... USING GIST (CAST(geom AS GEOGRAPHY));`

Answer (score 1):

The two points are in `4326`, so the where condition `WHERE ST_Dwithin (a.geom,b.geom,500)` is looking for points within 500 degrees of each others.

You could also cast to geography here

```
WHERE ST_Dwithin (a.geom::geography,b.geom::geography,500)
```

Also you don't need the `length` + `shortestline`. Computing the distance directly will give the proper result

```sql
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(a.geom::geography,b.geom::geography)  as distance_m
```

While it won't affect much the speed, there is no need to change a geometry to text to later cast it back as geometry. I suggest removing `st_asText`

Comment: Thank you! it works!

Comment: @MarceloEstebanLagosBustaman Great! Please consider marking this answer as accepted (green check mark to the left) so others know there is a working solution